# How do I find all occurrences of a character that *aren't* the first character in the line?

Tags: regex

I want to find all occurrences of the ">" character that are **not** at the beginning of the line.

For example:

```
This is a <em>test</em>, this is not a drill.

> Shouldn't
```

The first two ">" should be caught, but the last shouldn't, as it starts a line.

I tried: `(?<!$)>` to no avail.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That did not work to my knowledge. https://regex101.com/r/pP7dM5/1

Comment: @DougSmith: Add `m` flag in your regex101 demo

Comment: Because you didn't switch on the multiline modifier (m)

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative look-behind :

```
/(?<!^)>/gm
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/wW2hO3/1

Note that you need use multi-line flag (`m`) which makes the regex engine match the anchors for each line, instead of whole of string.